# DragDropContextProvider backend and window props must not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I am making a drag and drop web app that has many possible DragSources, so I was going to paginate them and update the state with the new set of DragSources. However, when I do update the state with the new set of DragSources, I get this error:
`DragDropContextProvider backend and window props must not change.`

Is it possible to change the list of dragSources with react-dnd, am I doing something wrong?

Help would be much appreciated!